# How to draw a line using slope in Pandas and Seaborn scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

How to make a line in the following code using slope and intercept ?

```
tips.plot(kind="scatter", x="total_bill", y="tip", figsize=(9,9), alpha=0.7)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: that does not make sense. For a simple line, you do not need a scatterplot. Do you want to plot a linear fit together with your data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to draw a line of best fit. The function below will draw on for you. With regards to displaying a line of best fit, you might be better off calcuting the variable with a linear regression.

```
plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 1))(np.unique(x)))
```